# symfony 1.4: recreating the database from new schema

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, mysql-error-1067

I'm trying to recreate the database from a new schema, but I keep getting the same error `Invalid default value for ...` I've changed the schema.yml so many times even removed the value that is causing this error, but it still shows. I'm still getting the same error no matter what I do.

I use `php symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load` but the schema.sql that gets generated is the same every time. I've deleted it, but somehow it has an idea of what the schema is that is different from the schema.yml that I'm editing.

I've tried Emptying the cache `symfony cc` and deleting the sql folder under data, and it' not working.

Any ideas ???

---edit---

I just realized that the database gets generated properly, but the build instruction gives me the same error unless I actually have an error in the schema.yml syntax

Comment: Please provide the schema code so people can identify the error.

Comment: the schema is irrelevant, because the error that is being thrown does not represent the schema.yml I am using

Comment: Try changing the encoding of the file. Try with UTF8 or ASCII, I've had a similar mistake and it was the problem. You can use notepad++ or any advanced text editor for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `doctrine:clean-model-files`. It will delete all generated model classes for models which no longer exist in your YAML schema.

Comment: haven't had a chance to try it, ended up going back to modx. Thanks though